# API for given name popularity

Tags: api

I'd like to find out how popular a name is in the United States, preferably by rank, but by number of people with that name would be good, too.

[The Social Security Administration keeps records of baby names going back to 1879](http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/). There's probably a way to determine the overall frequency of a name in the population, but I'd settle for getting the rank of a name in a given year, and using that as a (flawed) proxy for popularity.

This is possible through [their site](http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/), so I imagine just parsing the results of the right POST request would do it.

Currently I'm just running:

```
curl -d "year=2010&top=1000&number=p" http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi > 2010_top_1000.html
```

And then parsing the html, and doing a lookup in the resulting file.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:**
The most names you can get with the above method is 1000. You can get the whole list of baby names with a frequency of more than 5 name as a zip file here: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html.

Answer (score 2):

The US Census Bureau wondered the exact same thing, in 1990, and then they published this: http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html

Unfortunately I don't think they have done the same with the 2000 or 2010 data.